# WinSCP error while performing directory Sync

Tags: azure-webjobs, winscp-net

I've developed a .Net console application to run as a webjob under Azure App Service.

This console app is using WinSCP to transfer files from App Service Filesystem to an on-prem FTP Server.

The job is failing with below error:

> Upload of "D:\ ...\log.txt" failed: WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Error deleting file 'log.txt'. After resumable file upload the existing destination file must be deleted. If you do not have permissions to delete file destination file, you need to disable resumable file transfers.

Herein the code snippet I use to perform the directory sync (I've disabled deletion):

```
var syncResult = session.SynchronizeDirectories(SynchronizationMode.Remote, localFolder, remoteFolder, false,false);
```

Any clues on how to disable resumable file transfers ??

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TransferOptions.ResumeSupport`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#resumesupport):

```cs
var transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
transferOptions.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.Off;
var syncResult =
   session.SynchronizeDirectories(
       SynchronizationMode.Remote, localFolder, remoteFolder, false, false,
       transferOptions);
```